Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset in select query
I have the following code that is meant to get data from an online server:
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dtOnline As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ID, Description FROM stocklocations WHERE CoID = @CoID AND ShopID = @ShopID"
    Using con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(gen.connStringOnline)
        Using cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoID", gen.CoID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShopID", gen.shopID)
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 86400
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            con.Open()
            da.Fill(dtOnline)
            con.Dispose()
        End Using
    End Using

The line da.Fill(dtOnline) returns an error: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset

To check if it was a connection problem, I put the con.Open() line, and it connects.
Based on the similar posts here, I extended the command's timeout using cmd.CommandTimeout = 86400.
I have been able to establish connection with mysql Workbench and I am able to read, insert etc from there.
But on the code above, I still get the error on da.Fill(dtOnline)
I'm using mysql server 5.6.
Any ideas what else I can try?


As a test, I'd try using a data reader and see whether there's an exception thrown on the ExecuteReader call or the Read call. It sounds like it would be the latter but I think it's a test worth performing.

Is there an inner exception with more specific information?

@jmcilhinney, the inner exeption says {"Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework."}. But the character set in the online server is not utf8mb3, its utfmb4_general_ci

@PercyKumah Have you seen System.NotSupportedException: Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework?

@AndrewMorton your comment pointed me in the right direction. The solution provided here [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-easily-convert-utf8-tables-to-utf8mb4-in-mysql-5-5] solved my problem. Thank you!!

@PercyKumah Please feel free to delete this question - Stack Overflow lacks a mechanism to flag cross-site duplicates. The only alternative we have available is to downvote your question, which doesn't seem to be nice to me.
